# How to make a regex skip a middle section?

Tags: bash, awk

I have files with lines such as these:

```
@Dacor 125#Apples were stored in Section 1.#Delivered on 02/03/2023. All ok.#
```

I am trying to develop a regex so I use `gsub` to produce:

```
Apples were stored in Section 1
```

However, I don't know how I can use regex to skip a middle section sandwiched between two `#`, even if I treat `#` as a delimiter.

So far, I have tried:

```
awk 'match($0, /@([^#]+)#(.*)#/, arr) {print arr[2]}'
```

This generates:

```
Apples were stored in Section 1.#Delivered on 02/03/2023. All ok.
```

I am unable to get the correct output.

Comment: If your target string always appears between the first and the second occurrence of a `#`, just use that as delimiter, and print the second column: `awk -F\# '{print $2}'`

Comment: *I use gsub to produce:* I fail to see usage of `gsub` function in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Use [`cut`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) to print the second column in `#`-delimited file:

```
cut -f2 -d'#' in_file > out_file
```

**Method 2:**

Use [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

```
grep -Po '^[^#]*#\K[^#]*' in_file > out_file
```

Here, GNU `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.

`^[^#]*#` : beginning of the line, then 0 or more non-`#` characters, followed by literal `#`.
`\K` : Cause the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the `\K` and not include it in the match. Specifically, ignore the preceding part of the regex when printing the match.

**See also:**

- [perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Answer (score 3):

Always keep in mind [this saying](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
> regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

If you really wanted to use a regexp for some reason one way would be this, using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/#([^#]+)/,a) { print a[1] }' file
Apples were stored in Section 1.
```

or using any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/#([^#]+)/) { print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1) }' file
Apples were stored in Section 1.
```

but as others have pointed out all you need is this, using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'#' '{print $2}' file
Apples were stored in Section 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer described how to repair existing code, rather than proposing brand new solution. Problem is that in your code

```
awk 'match($0, /@([^#]+)#(.*)#/, arr) {print arr[2]}'
```

`.*` does match in greedy-fashion (as much as possible), whilst you need non-greedy-fashion. Use all-but-`#` as you have already done for 1st capturing group to get desired output, let `file.txt` content be

```
@Dacor 125#Apples were stored in Section 1.#Delivered on 02/03/2023. All ok.#
```

then

```
awk 'match($0, /@([^#]+)#([^#]+)#/, arr) {print arr[2]}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Apples were stored in Section 1.
```

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*